# Writing an installer with choose folder option in osx

Tags: macos, applescript, installation, dmg, pkgbuild

I am writing an installer for plugin to Adobe photoshop in mac os. So, when I googled I could find that installer for mac os is coming in two formats;dmg and pkg. 
 In dmg there is no option to ask the user to select the folder location of the software(Adobe photoshop in this case). This is required to place the plugin files in the adobe photoshop software location. 
 Whereas in pkg, there is option to ask only to the hard drive level and not to the folder location level( I might be wrong here. Please correct me if I am wrong).

Applescript might solve the problem, but I need to include a license agreement for the customer to accept it and then proceed with the installation, which made me not to select applescript

Please help me to solve this issue and suggest a approach.

Comment: Package installers (.pkg, .mpkg) are generally built to install it's contents in specific locations (within folders, etc,), so your conclusion is not correct. A .dmg is not an installer at all, but simply a disk image (think of it like a usb drive), although OS X does not allow programs to autorun from a .dmg.

Comment: thanks for your reply and correcting me.  Can you suggest a tool which I could you use to create package installer ?

Comment: Yes, my recommendation would be an application called [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) — it's excellent, and free. You can also build a package installers from the command-line via `productbuild` and `pkgbuild`...

Comment: I tried using the application packages. In the destination page in the installer, how do I ask the user to specify a Adobe photoshop folder inside the Applications folder

Comment: You'll need to read the documentation, as that is your best way of understanding how to do that.